# Building Daemon or Service Apps with Office 365 mail throwing 401 error code

Tags: office365

I am following 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/01/22/building-demon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow.aspx

I am doing programming to generate token in Java. I took AADL libraries from git for java.

Instead of code suggested in the blog for .net I am using following code for java,
String token = null;
        String tenant="my_tenant";

```
    String authority = "https://login.windows.net/"+tenant+"/oauth2/authorize";
    ExecutorService service = null;
    service=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    try {
        AuthenticationContext authenticationContext =  new AuthenticationContext(authority, false, service);
        String certfile = "filapath/mycert.pfx";
        InputStream pkcs12Certificate=new FileInputStream(certfile);



        AsymmetricKeyCredential credential = AsymmetricKeyCredential.create("client_id", pkcs12Certificate,"password");
        System.out.println("X509 is fine!");

        Future<AuthenticationResult> future=authenticationContext.acquireToken("https://outlook.office365.com", credential, null);
        System.out.println("Token Received"+future.get().getAccessToken());
        token=future.get().getAccessToken();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But the when I access mail REST APi using the token acquired thorugh this process, it gives me HTTP 401 error.
Am I doing something wrong in specifying the X509 certificate keys??
or something else?

Comment: Issue is resolved now! I was doing silly mistake.

Comment: what was your mistake? I'm having "Unauthorized" issues as well

Comment: Hi robertmiles3, I was receiving correct token by calling future.get().getAccessToken(). But, In order to fetch email data, I was calling HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

   con.setRequestMethod("GET");
   con.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
   con.setRequestProperty("Authorization",token);, authorization header should be set like, con.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Bearer "+token);. Then it worked! I am able to fetch email and calendar details.

Comment: How do you upload the certificate ?

Comment: @WowBow The link in my question had all the needed steps. It seems microsoft has removed that link. I will try to search if I can find similar content somewhere else.

Comment: this is the link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2015/01/21/building-daemon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow/